# unable to Webscrape dropdown item [Python][beautifulsoup]

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am new to webscraping, i am scraping a website - https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/22/uti-mastershare-fund-regular-plan/

In this,i want to scrape this text - Regular Plan
[image]

But the thing is, when i do it using inspect element,
code -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys

url = 'https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/newsnapshot.asp?schemecode=22'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
regular_direct = soup.find('span',class_="filter-option pull-left").text

print(regular_direct)
```

i get none in printing, and i don't know why, the code in inspect element and view page source is also different, because in view page source, this span and class is not there.
why i am getting none?? can anyone please tell me and how can i get that text and why inspect element code and view page source code are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the selector because the html source that gets downloaded is different.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import sys

url = 'https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/newsnapshot.asp?schemecode=22'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
regular_direct = soup.find("select", {"id":"select-plan"}).find("option",{"selected":"selected"}).get_text(strip=True)

print(regular_direct)
```

Output:

```
Regular plan
```

Comment: yes, it is being scraped but can you tell me should i scrape using inspect element or using view source code?? and how did you get that selector i mean specific selector? or how do you know that you should use this?

Comment: Inspect element is on browser, there's no guarantee that the same html will be sent using `requests`. So, best option is to open the html downloaded. using `requests` and then use inspect element

Comment: ok, Thank you so much, i got stuck in this from yesterday,

Comment: @Prabhatkumar To clarify why, `requests` does not execute Javascript while your browser does. To mitigate this, you can use `requests-html` which does execute Javascript and has a similar API as `requests`. https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/